# Who should be responsible for "program startup with three std streams opened"?

Tags: c, kernel, posix, stdin

I'm working on my study purpose OS kernel, now I have a confusion about creating time of standard streams.

The famous "APUE" said that "By convention, UNIX System shells associate file descriptor 0 with the standard input of a process, file descriptor 1 with the standard output, and file descriptor 2 with
the standard error.This convention is used by the shells and many applications; it is
not a feature of the UNIX kernel."

And If I'm not mistaken, fork() and execve() won't change those opened files. Does that mean Kernel has no responsibility for preparing those standard stream for user process?(And the kernel should not do that by convention?) Does the c library source file affording program entry point such as crt.c also shouldn't do so?

From the answer under this [stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437602/does-posix-standardize-the-file-descriptor-numbers), I can only make sure that POSIX.1 only requires these three streams should correspond to fileno 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preparing the three standard streams is generally done by the command-line shell. When a shell is about to run a program, it can fork, configure the three standard streams (connecting each to a terminal, a pipe, or a file as desired), and then use one of the `exec*` functions to execute the program.

Comment: Does this imply that programs may start with zero open file descriptors? Even the so called standard streams are not guaranteed to be there?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: You can write a program that closes the file descriptors and calls an `exec*` routine to start another program without any open streams. If it is a C program with the standard C start-up code in it, it may encounter errors when it attempts to do things with file descriptors it assumes are open.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira And a program can do other nasty things with the exec* routines. By convention, argument 0 (`main()`'s `argv[0]`) contains a program name and the number of arguments (`main()`'s `argc`) is at least 1. But `exec*` allows that convention to be broken by setting the number of arguments to 0, so that `main()`'s `argv[0]` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In theory a kernel provides features that "run-time environments" can be built on top of. For example, you might support multiple isolated processes, where one process has a C run-time environment (with POSIX and standard C library, etc), and another process can be something completely different (e.g. a new futuristic run-time environment designed for GUIs) that doesn't have any reason to care about C or POSIX or the "standard for the wrong run-time environment" streams.

For a "C/POSIX" run-time environment; the old Unix/POSIX way is to use `pipe()`, `fork()`, `close()` and finally `exec()` so that the parent process creates the pipes and passes them to the child process; which means a kernel would need to provide the low level features needed for a library to implement those function calls. A more standard approach (standard C without requiring POSIX on top of that) is a `system()` function that takes care of all the mess but has less flexibility; and a more modern approach is some kind of OS specific `create_process()` that gives a better compromise between mess/hassle, flexibility, efficiency and security problems.

With this in mind, in general:

a) It's your OS, you decide which run-time environments you want to support, and how, and where

b) If you choose to care about POSIX, then it'd probably be easiest for kernel to provide the low level functionality that a C/POSIX library would depend on for its implementation of `pipe()`, `fork()`, `close()` and `exec()`; and then let the same C/POSIX library implement anything else (e.g. `system()` on top of that. In that case completely unrelated run-time environments may still use the same low level functionality provided by the kernel in different ways, and may still follow the "3 pipes/streams" for the sake of (partial or full) compatibility.

c) the low level functionality that a C/POSIX library would depend on for its implementation of `pipe()`, `fork()`, `close()` and `exec()` may look nothing like those functions at all. For example, a kernel might implement "fixed sized/small message passing" and shared memory, and a C library could implement pipes on top of that, where the kernel doesn't actually support anything like pipes itself.